# SIGFPE: Floating-point exception backtrace for this error: 0x7F70C71AF7D7

Tags: floating-point, fortran, gfortran

I use a Fortran 90 model under Ubuntu 14.04. The gfortran 95 compiler (gfortran 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) and the gcc 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 are installed by Ubuntu Software Center. After I ran the model I get the following error message:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.
Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F70C71AF7D7
#1  0x7F70C71AFDDE
#2  0x7F70C68EAD3F
#3  0x7F70C6EB6913
```

Could someone explain me what these backtrace codes mean? How can I handle these errors?

Comment: Those numbers are values of the instruction pointer that some stack unwinding procedure found on the stack.  You may (or may not) be able to feed them through `addr2line` to get function names and line numbers out of them.

Comment: I tried addr2line and gdb to get the function names and line numbers  but neither found it. `(gdb) info symbol 0x7F2B31E0D7D7
No symbol matches 0x7F2B31E0D7D7`, `gdb) info line *0x7F2B31E0D7D7
No line number information available for address 0x7f2b31e0d7d7`, `addr2line -e KiD_SC_2D.exe 0x7F2B31E0D7D7
??:0`. Is there any other way to handle this error?

Answer (score 9):

Use the options `-O -Wall -fcheck=all -g -fbacktrace` during compilation and run the executable.  If this does not provide the necessary information, try running your program under gdb and/or valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, when I compiled a Fortran95 code.
In my case, I just debugged my code. There was a wrong mathematical operation (division by zero). Once I fixed it, the compilation error was gone.
Try to check your code for math error.
I hope it can help you.