# Are hashtagged error message useful in debugging?

Tags: debugging, gdb, valgrind

I sometimes encounter error messages while executing a fortran/C program. For example, after running my present fortran program I have got the following message in my screen output.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x101f584f2
#1  0x101f58cae
#2  0x7fff88661f19
#3  0x101e7984c
#4  0x101e7a8dd
#5  0x101e7b16f
#6  0x101e7cab3
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I am worried if the hashtagged symbols mean anything to a debugger? Can one exploit those symbols using `gdb` or `valgrind`? If yes, how to backtrace?

PS. There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557952/sigfpe-floating-point-exception-backtrace-for-this-error-0x7f70c71af7d7) where @ tmyklebu says, *You may (or may not) be able to feed them through addr2line to get function names and line numbers out of them.* But he/she doesn't tell how to do.

Answer (score 0):

> I am worried if the hashtagged symbols mean anything to a debugger?

These messages are not hastagged. Here the `#` symbol simply stands for (frame) number.

Besides, there is no reason to feed this output to the debugger. If you ran the program *under* debugger, and then used `(gdb) where` command, you would get similar output, with additional info (symbol names, possibly file/line info). But since you didn't, you now need to use tools other than debugger (e.g. `addr2line`).